# Написал код для окна, выводит ошибку в виде ;

Tags: c++

```
#include <Windows.h>

int CALLBACK winMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE, PWSTR szCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    MSG msg{};
    HWND hwnd{};
    WNDCLASSEX wc{ sizeof(WNDCLASSEX) };
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hbrBackground = reinterpret_cast<HBRUSH>(GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH));
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(nullptr, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon(nullptr, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = [](HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)->LRESULT
    {
        switch (uMsg)
        {
        case WM_DESTROY:
        {
            PostQuitMessage(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }
        return 0;
        }
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    };
    wc.lpszClassName = L"MyApp";
    wc.lpszMenuName = nullptr;
    wc.style = CS_VREDRAW | CS_HREDRAW;

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wc))
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    if (hwnd = CreateWindow(wc.lpszClassName, L"Заголовок!", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 0, 0, 600, 600, nullptr, nullptr, wc.hInstance, nullptr); hwnd == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return static_cast<int>(msg.wParam);
}
```

[image: инфа]

Answer (score 1):

Вот это:

```
if (hwnd = CreateWindow(wc.lpszClassName, L"Заголовок!", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 0, 0, 600, 600, nullptr, nullptr, wc.hInstance, nullptr); hwnd == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
```

замените на это:

```
if ((hwnd = CreateWindow(wc.lpszClassName, L"Заголовок!", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 0, 0, 600, 600, nullptr, nullptr, wc.hInstance, nullptr)) == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
```

Ещё можно оставить всё как есть, но в настройках проекта установить стандарт С++17.

Comment: а можно было просто поднять версию стандарта до 17.

Comment: @KoVadim Можно. Просто это нормально выглядит для инициализации, а здесь присваивание. И при просмотре кода кажется, что написали `=` вместо `==`. Но добалю в ответ и про стандарт.